# CSS not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am writing signature on a `canvas`. (Flash canvas) - Using jquery jsSignature plugin.

http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/

Signature color is black. But the signature is not visible. Actually it is writing to canvas. Canvas background is red.

If I close the browser and reopen the closed browser it is showing the signature. But again if I refresh or go to next page and coming back, again signature does not appear on canvas.

I know question is not reasonable and more down-votes can appear, still I am looking for some suggestions.

It is working on IE6 and IE9.

Not understanding whether it is CSS issue or JavaScript issue. Please help.

I can only give below information. I know this is not enough. I am unable to reproduce this in jsfiddle. Because lack of time.

CSS

```
    #signatureparentAppSig {
        background-color: #red;
        color: black;
        padding : 0px;
    }
```

Javascript:-

```
$appSig.jSignature({'UndoButton':true, 'extraActionClass' : 'appSigActions', 'strokeManagingFieldId' : 'app_num_strok', 'background-color':'white', 'sizeRatio' : '4', 'lineWidth' : '2', 'width' : '550', 'height' : '157'})
```

Comment: con you replicate the issue on jsfiddle ?

Comment: You missed a minor detail, Include the relevant code so we can actually help you. And no don't link to your site, if you don't take the time to ask a decent question why should we bother to answer ?

Comment: I have added the codes. I can not add everything here. Because it is very huge coding.

Comment: Not understanding how it works when I close the tab and reopen again. But second refresh it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and/or [normalize](http://nicolasgallagher.com/) to make it display properly (like a block) so it will fit in your design. However, the functionality of the canvas is not usable in a browser that doesnt support it.